# Fragment's onCreateView called before activity's onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have my `VehicleListActivity` which passes a `Bundle` to my fragment.
This is activity's `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vehicle_list);
    vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String userID = intent.getStringExtra("userID");
    LoadingVehicleListFragment f = new LoadingVehicleListFragment();
    Bundle fArguments = new Bundle();
    fArguments.putString("userID", userID);
    f.setArguments(fArguments);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.loadingVehicleFragment, f).commit();
}
```

and this is fragment's `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    activity = (VehicleListActivity)getActivity();
    context = activity;
    listener = activity;
    String userID = getArguments().getString("userID");
    getUserInformation(userID);

    return inflater.inflate(com.devspark.progressfragment.R.layout.fragment_progress, container, false);
}
```

I've noticed that fragment's `onCreateView` is called before activity's `onCreate`, so `getArguments()` in my fragment returns a null, which causes a null pointer exception.
Where should I put `getArguments()` in my fragment to avoid this exception?

EDIT: as requested this is the whole fragment's source:

```
public class LoadingVehicleListFragment extends ProgressFragment
{
private VehicleListListener listener;
private VehicleListActivity activity;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(com.devspark.progressfragment.R.layout.fragment_progress, container, false);
}

/*@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    int c = 0;
    listener = (VehicleListActivity)getActivity();
    getUserInformation(getArguments().getString("userID"));
}*/

private void getUserVehicles(String userID)
{
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            try
            {
                HashMap resultMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, HashMap.class);
                VehicleListRequest.ErrorCode errorCode = VehicleListRequest.ErrorCode.fromInt(Integer.parseInt(resultMap.get("error_code").toString()));

                switch (errorCode)
                {
                    case NONE:
                        parseVehicleFromMap(resultMap);
                        break;
                    case EXCEPTION_CAUGHT:
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder2.setMessage("Eccezione catturata. \n Messaggio: " + resultMap.get("error_message"));
                        builder2.create().show();
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO gestire
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    VehicleListRequest request = new VehicleListRequest(userID, responseListener, null);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

public void getUserInformation(final String userID)
{
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            try
            {
                HashMap resultMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, HashMap.class);
                GetUserRequest.ErrorCode errorCode = GetUserRequest.ErrorCode.fromInt(Integer.parseInt(resultMap.get("error_code").toString()));

                switch (errorCode)
                {
                    case NONE:
                        listener.setLoggedUser(User.fromMap(resultMap));
                        getUserVehicles(userID);
                        break;
                    case EXCEPTION_CAUGHT:
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder2.setMessage("Eccezione catturata. \n Messaggio: " + resultMap.get("error_message"));
                        builder2.create().show();
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO gestire
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    GetUserRequest request = new GetUserRequest(userID, responseListener, null);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

private void parseVehicleFromMap(HashMap map)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (map.containsKey(String.valueOf(i)))
    {
        final Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
        HashMap vehicleMap = (HashMap) map.get(String.valueOf(i));

        v.setPlate(vehicleMap.get("plate").toString());
        v.setKm(vehicleMap.get("km") == null ? null : Integer.parseInt(vehicleMap.get("km").toString()));
        v.setInUse(Integer.parseInt(vehicleMap.get("in_use").toString()) == 1);
        v.setFuelQuantity(Double.parseDouble(vehicleMap.get("actual_fuel_quantity").toString()));
        v.setEffectiveFuelEconomy(Double.parseDouble(vehicleMap.get("effective_fuel_economy").toString()));
        v.setInsuranceDate(vehicleMap.get("insurance_date") == null ? null : new LocalDate(vehicleMap.get("insurance_date").toString()));
        v.setMatriculationDate(new LocalDate(vehicleMap.get("matriculation_date").toString()));
        v.setLatitude(vehicleMap.get("latitude") == null ? null : Double.parseDouble(vehicleMap.get("latitude").toString()));
        v.setLongitude(vehicleMap.get("longitude") == null ? null : Double.parseDouble(vehicleMap.get("longitude").toString()));
        v.setUser(activity.getLogged());

        listener.addVehicle(v);

        i++;
    }
}
} // end class
```

this is error logs:

```
03-27 18:30:47.274 4966-4966/clyky.cartracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: clyky.cartracker, PID: 4966
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{clyky.cartracker/clyky.cartracker.activities.VehicleListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                at clyky.cartracker.activities.fragments.LoadingVehicleListFragment.onActivityCreated(LoadingVehicleListFragment.java:51)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2193)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1323)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1523)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1585)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2832)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:603)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

before of these exceptions, I've also got some "failed binder transactions", like these:

```
03-27 18:30:41.955 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 100)
```

03-27 18:30:41.956 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/AndroidIME: aqx: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
03-27 18:30:41.999 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 100)
03-27 18:30:42.000 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/AndroidIME: aqx: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
03-27 18:30:42.001 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 100)
03-27 18:30:42.002 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/AndroidIME: aqx: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
03-27 18:30:42.005 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 100)
03-27 18:30:42.007 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/AndroidIME: aqx: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
03-27 18:30:42.008 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 100)
03-27 18:30:42.010 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/AndroidIME: aqx: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
03-27 18:30:42.026 1452-5094/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 168)
03-27 18:30:42.031 1452-5095/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 168)
03-27 18:30:43.509 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 100)
03-27 18:30:43.510 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/AndroidIME: aqx: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
03-27 18:30:43.510 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 100)
03-27 18:30:43.512 1452-1452/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/AndroidIME: aqx: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
03-27 18:30:43.542 1452-5121/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 168)
03-27 18:30:43.547 1452-5120/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 168)

however, they starts to appear before the operations that throw exception, so I think that these errors aren't influential.

Comment: why are you calling super.onAttach in onCreateview? Also you can `getArguments()` in `onCraateView` the drawback being slower onCreateView execution

Comment: @Bhargav sorry for the `onAttach`, it was a copy-paste error 'cause I've tried to do `getArguments` in fragment's `onAttach` first

Comment: wait is the view even inflating for the fragment?

Comment: are you sure getArguments() returns null,Please post log trace. How  onCreateView() can be called if fragment transaction is not initiated in onCreate of activity

Comment: @Jagroshan yes, I'm sure of that. I've posted the log trace, and I've noticed that before with a watcher

Comment: okay and how you ensured onCreate was not called before. Are you sure some other code is not using this fragment

Comment: you don't read the other comments, however now the activity's onCreate is called before: I've used breakpoints to see that: the first called is in the activity, and the breakpoint I've put in the fragment is never called (simply the app stops running without any error, lol). however, if I remove the breakpoints on the activity the breakpoints in the fragment are called, and getArguments returns null there

Comment: failed binder transaction can be the cause but logs you posted have no such entry for your process

Comment: the code getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.loadingVehicleFragment, f).commit();
} this will start callbacks of fragment like onCreateView. So what I meant was fragment transaction code need to run first.

Answer (score 1):

The `onActivityCreated()` is called after the `onCreateView()` method when the host activity is created. Activity and fragment instance have been created as well as the view hierarchy of the activity. At this point, view can be accessed with the `findViewById()` method. example. In this method you can instantiate objects which require a Context object.

Try accessing it there, also do not store context in fragments always call `getActivity()`

That Null Pointer is caused by the flow of execution in the android framework,`onCreateView()` The system calls this callback when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View component from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.
Therefore it is called first, hence giving the null pointer exception.

Comment: try getting the arguments in that method.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've tried to get arguments in `onActivityCreated` as you said, but it still not working. Now the activity's `onCreated` is called well, but `onActivityCreated` is never called (the breakpoint I've put there it's never called)

Comment: this is wired, i would recommend just using shared preference file to share the content of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vehicle_list);
    vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

    String userID;
    Bunlde bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null){
        userID = bundle.getString("userID");
    }

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
          LoadingVehicleListFragment f = new LoadingVehicleListFragment();
          Bundle fArguments = new Bundle();
          fArguments.putString("userID", userID);
          f.setArguments(fArguments);
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.loadingVehicleFragment, f).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I've tried this, but `getArguments` in `onActivityCreated` still returns null

Comment: can you send whole fragment code? there's something wrong.

Comment: i edited my code. i think you do not put userId when you're starting your activity.

Comment: thank you but yes, I've put "userID" as parameter to pass. it's directly `getArguments` that returns null, it's not that "userID" doesn't exist.